# Can more than one EAR be deployed to same Weblogic Node?

Tags: jakarta-ee, weblogic

If Weblogic has one Managed server (i.e. other than the AdminServer) running at a specific port,

does it make sense to deploy more than one EAR to that Manager Server (or Node) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, definitely. In that case you should also use WorkManagers to ensure that one application does not hog the threads.

Here is a link to the WorkManager documentation online: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e13701/self_tuned.htm

Here is a video demo of the WorkManager feature: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NnRcM29zJb4